# scanf can not read float data after string in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to parse input such as `101-John-3.4` but in last sequence `float` data `3.4` is not read. How can I solve this problem?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("Enter ID-Name-CGPA respectively: ");
    scanf("%lld-%[^-]s-%f", id[i], name[i], cgpa[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is `id`? What is `name`? What is `cgpa`? Can you please show their declarations?

Comment: Also the `"%["` format specifier does *not* end with an `s`. Perhaps [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might be helpful to read?

Comment: Remove `s` from `%[^-]s`. (maybe `scanf("%lld-%[^-]-%f", &id[i], name[i], &cgpa[i]);`)

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the trailing `s` from the scanset directive in the format string:

```
scanf("%lld-%[^-]-%f", id[i], name[i], cgpa[i]);
```

The `s` is not a part of the scanset directive, and so `scanf()` is attempting, and failing, to match an `s` in the input. This could be detected if the code were checking the return value from the call to `scanf()`, which is always a good practice.

Also, no declarations are shown, but if `id[]` is declared as an array of `long long int`s, and `cgpa[]` is declared as an array of `float`s, then the address operator should be used. Also, to protect against buffer overflow you should always specify a maximum number of characters to be read by the `%s` or `%[]` directives. Input that is too large would cause the program to attempt to write past the end of the array `name[]`, leading to undefined behavior. For example, if `name` is an array of 30 `char`s, i.e.`char name[30];`, then you need `%29[^-]-`. You need to specify 29 instead of 30 because this number tells `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to *read*; the `%s` and `%[]` directives always write at least one character, a `\0` to create a string, so specifying a maximum of 29 characters to be read ensures that at most 30 characters will be written:

```
int ret_val = scanf("%lld-%29[^-]-%f", &id[i], name[i], &cgpa[i]);
/* ret_val should be 3 */
```

Comment: Also tell the OP to pass `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store to the array pointed to by `name[i]`.